# Function doesn't change value, when applied to nested list

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a function which iterates over list of lists. If it finds the value, which is a list itself, it should create a string from this value and insert it instead of the original one:

```
def lst_to_str(lst):
for x in lst:
    for y in x:
        i = 0
        if type(y) == list:
            x[i] = ",".join(y)
        i +=1
return lst
```

The problem is, when I apply this function to pd.DataFrame column

```
df['pdns'] = df['pdns'].apply(lambda x: lst_to_str(x))
```

It returns me the original nested list:

```
[['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], ['a1', 'b1', 'd1', 'c1'],['a2', 'b2', 'c2', ['d2_1', 'd2_2']]]
```

Instead of:

```
[['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], ['a1', 'b1', 'd1', 'c1'],['a2', 'b2', 'c2', 'd2_1, d2_2']]
```

Comment: Can you show us what df['pdns'] looks like?

Comment: It is a pandas.Series object, where every row is a three-level nested list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is wrong. In your function definition, you're not making any change to 1st and in the end you return 1st. You're checking some condition and then you change the value of your counter (x). Correct this problem and try again